# How do I know when the screen goes to dim state in Android

Tags: android

I'm developing an application that can run a service and then when the screen goes to dim state (It's about 6s after the screen goes off) the application will show something (like a Toast or activity or ...)

I can get the time out of the screen and then use the latest action (touch event, key event) to count when screen will go to dim state but sometimes it doesn't work (like when the user uses camera, watchs movie, etc.)

I have an other idea: I will get the time that screen goes to dim state (or the remaining time until the screens go off - like 7s, 6s, ...)

Can anybody help me to get that time?

Answer (score 0):

Register a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_SCREEN_OFF

Comment: Thanks. I tried this before but How can I get when the screen go off, I mean the time when screen go off (not about current state off or on of screen)

Comment: You mean how long until it does?  I'm not sure you can.

Comment: yes, it is. Or the system time count value before screen turn off (ex: 1s,...2s... to 15s then screen turn of). Can I get that value?